# Link on opening Mobile Application does not works on IOS?

Tags: android, ios, anchor

When you reach the tablet form, the icons for social media link will show and the desktop icon will close, the problem is it is not working on IOS phone but works on android phones.
Is there something special on IOS that it can't open the apps?

Here is my code

```
 <div class="social-icons">
   <span class="social-icons-mobile">
     <a href="fb://page/1111111">
       <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
     </a>                          
     <a href="instagram://sample/" target="_blank">
       <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
     </a>                               
   </span>

   <span class="social-icons-large">
     <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sample/">
       <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
     </a>                          
     <a href="https://www.instagram.com/sample/" target="_blank">
       <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
     </a>                               
   </span>
 </div>
```

edit:
when I used the profile in fb, it works on ios but not in android